# Trouble writing test for validating uniqueness of value in my join table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, activerecord, rspec

A little while ago I was able to find a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34667213/validate-uniqueness-of-name-in-a-habtm-association) on how to create a uniqueness validation in my join table:

```
class Album < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :album_artists
  has_many :artists, through: :album_artists
end

class AlbumArtist < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :album
  belongs_to :artist

  validate :uniqueness_of_album_artist

  private
    def uniqueness_of_album_artist
      if self.artist.albums.where(name: self.album.name).any?
        album.errors[:base] << "Artist already has an album by this name"
      end
    end
end

class Artist < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :album_artists
  has_many :albums, through: :album_artists
end
```

I now want to write a test for my `AlbumArtist's` `uniqueness_of_album_artist` validator. Here's what I came up with:

```
it 'validates that album is unique to artist' do
  artist = FactoryGirl.create(:artist)
  artist.albums.push(FactoryGirl.create(:album, name: "Test"), FactoryGirl.create(:album, name: "Test"))

  album_artist = artist.album_artists.last

  expect(album_artist).to be_invalid
  expect(album_artist.errors[:base]).to include('Artist already has an album by this name')
end
```

Strangely though my test fails:

```
Failure/Error: expect(album_artist).to be_invalid
       expected `#<AlbumArtist id: 2, artist_id: 1, album_id: 2, created_at: "2016-07-05 14:57:13", updated_at: "2016-07-05 14:57:13">.invalid?` to return true, got false
```

I went ahead and did some debugging after this but when I test whether the artist has two identically named albums, it returns `true`, thus proving it to be invalid.

```
p artist.album_artists.first.album.name == artist.album_artists.last.album.name # returns true
```

What's going on here?

Comment: Interesting I had a problem with uniquess with similar models. I thougth you could use `-> { uniq }` but now I realise it's for display only. Is this the only solution to check uniqueness ?

Comment: @Marc-Andre well...the only one I've come across.

Answer (score 0):

Your test is failing because the artist_album is valid.  What is happening is that the last one is never created because of your validation but it isn't raising when it fails.   Try this:

```
it 'validates that album is unique to artist' do
  artist = FactoryGirl.create(:artist)
  album = FactoryGirl.create(:album)
  valid_artist_album = AlbumArtist.create(artist: artist, album: album)
  invalid_album_artist = AlbumArtist.new(artist: artist, album: album)

  expect(invalid_album_artist).to be_invalid

end
```

I am editing this post to use the code highlighting. So if you do this: what happens?

```
it 'validates that album is unique to artist' do
  artist = FactoryGirl.create(:artist)
  album = FactoryGirl.create(:album)
  AlbumArtist.create!(artist: artist, album: album)
  invalid_album_artist = AlbumArtist.create!(artist: artist, album: album)

  expect(invalid_album_artist).to be_invalid

end
```

What happens?  If you make it to the expect line your validation is not working.  If you raise an exception on the second create then your validation is working.  I think that since you said that the earlier test said invalid_album_artist was in fact valid that your validation is not working but changing your test to this will validate that for certain.

Comment: Hey. Despite the typo for the `AlbumArtist` class and the `invalid_album_artist` local variable I got the error: `undefined method 'build' for #<Class:0x007f91d1a3f178>`

Comment: Oops my mistake.  I updated the answer to use new rather than build.

Comment: Not getting the build error anymore but it's evaluating to `true`: `expected '#<AlbumArtist id: nil, artist_id: 1, album_id: 1, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>.invalid?' to return true, got false`

Comment: what happens if you try running: "valid_artist_album = AlbumArtist.create!(artist: artist, album: album) AlbumArtist.create!(artist: artist, album: album)

Comment: Did you want this all in the same variable declaration for `valid_artist_album`? Otherwise I get a syntax error.

Comment: If your validation is actually working calling "AlbumArtist.create!(artist: artist, album: album) " 2 times should result in an exception being raised.  That is what I am hoping to validate.  My theory is that your validation is not working.  If you can call the create with the ! as above 2 times, then the test I have written above is in fact working but your validation is broken.

Comment: Based on my validator in the OP what do you think is the problem. I can confirm that the validator works on the front-end.

Comment: I updated the other answer so I could use the code highlighting/formatting.  Try that and let me know what happens

Comment: Hey. With this new code I got the same result: `expected '#<AlbumArtist id: 2, artist_id: 1, album_id: 1, created_at: "2016-07-06 12:24:40", updated_at: "2016-07-06 12:24:40">.invalid?' to return true, got false`

Comment: Ok so your backend validation is not working.  I am guessing that if it is working on the front end it is because you have front end validation.

Comment: From your point of view, does this statement look correct? `self.artist.albums.where(name: self.album.name).any?` (this is the validation). It should also be noted that this validation is on the join table, `AlbumArtist`.

Comment: No that doesn't look right and the test proves that.  can you try something more like "validates_uniqueness_of :artist_id, :scope => :album_id" on your AlbumArtist model.

Comment: Wait I just remembered. This isn't necessarily checking for an ID match but an identical string match of the `name` value. Not sure if your validator would accomplish that.